# How do I use an array that has been returned from a function in a foreach loop

Tags: c#

```
static Array Matrix(int Rows, int Columns)
{
    int[,] Lottery = new int[Rows,Columns];  
    for (int i = 0; i < Lottery.GetLength(0); i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Lottery.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            Lottery[i, j] = RandomNum(1, 46);       
            Console.Write("{0,3},", Lottery[i, j]); 
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        return Lottery;
    }
}
```

I have this function to initiate and print a matrix, and I want to do a `foreach` loop that checks all the numbers in each row, but when I do `foreach (int i in Matrix)`, it tells me that I cannot operate on a method group, and when I do `foreach (int i in Lottery)`, it tells me that `Lottery` is a namespace.

I'm a beginner and I don't know what to do.

Comment: `foreach (int i in Matrix)` is incorrect because you should invoke Matrix method with 2 parameters; try `foreach (int i in Matrix(3,4))`

Comment: Additionally you should change your method signature to return an `int[]` like this: `private static int[,] Matrix(int Rows, int Columns)`

Comment: note also that you can declare your method as `static int[,] Matrix(int Rows, int Columns)`; it will be type-safe and will allow to use the same nested `for` loops with result of method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no meaning in calling like

```
foreach (int i in Matrix)
```

because Matrix is a Funtion or Method. And also you are not passing parameters required for that function..

For your need first prepare the Array, and then check..

Do the checking like this

```
Array lottery = Matrix(5, 5);
foreach (int number in lottery)
{
    // check number as required
}
```